# Exception thrown when adding a value to an Insert Parameter

Tags: c#, ado.net

I'm trying to create an Access Database and to add a table with some values. For some reasons the code below throws an exception when adding an integer into the Insert Parameter. Can someone spot what might be wrong?

```
var Name = DateTime.Now.ToString("H_mm_ss");

ADOX.CatalogClass cat = new ADOX.CatalogClass();

cat.Create("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
        "Data Source="+ "C:\\test\\" + Name + ".mdb;" +
        "Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5");

ADODB.Connection con = cat.ActiveConnection as ADODB.Connection;

ADOX.Table t = new Table();
t.Name = "Table1";
t.Columns.Append("Field1", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adInteger);
t.Columns.Append("Field2", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, 50);

cat.Tables.Append(t);

ADODB.Command cmdInsert = new ADODB.Command();
cmdInsert.ActiveConnection = con;

cmdInsert.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table1(Field1, Field2)" + " VALUES (?, ?)";

cmdInsert.CommandType = ADODB.CommandTypeEnum.adCmdText;

ADODB.Parameter param1 = cmdInsert.CreateParameter(
    "Field1",                                   // Parameter name 
    ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adInteger,               // Parameter type
    ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput,  // Parameter direction 
    -1,                                         // Max size of value in bytes 
    69);                                        // Parameter value 

 // throws InvalidCastException
cmdInsert.Parameters.Append(param1);
```

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: I'm not at work right now but I believe it was an InvalidCastException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that changing to ADODB version 2.7 fixes my problem. I was using version 2.8 when I created this thread.